# Comparing two tsv files

Tags: shell-script, awk, bioinformatics

I am trying to compare two tsv files. The file to be queried (file1) looks like:

```
Chr      Start      End
chr1    234738546   234738934
chr1    234792654   234793537
chr1    234908151   234908864
chr1    235097868   235098170
chr1    236080566   236081347
chr1    240307621   240308262
chr1    240308207   240308637
chr1    240308546   240308962
chr1    242627058   242627262
chr1    243923195   243923709
```

The second column of another file (file2) contains numbers that I wish to check, if lying, between the numbers in column 2 and 3 in the and repeat it until condition is satisfied.

eg: `242627060` lies between `242627058` & `242627262`

File2 looks like:

```
Chr    Centre_Coord Ignore_this_col   Secondary Information
chr1    234765055   234765056   NR_033927_LINC00184     .   +
chr1    234782033   234782034   NR_125944_LOC101927787  .   +
chr1    234859787   234859788   NR_038856_LINC01132     .   +
chr1    234895802   234895803   NR_148962_PP2672        .   -
chr1    235099745   235099746   NR_125945_LOC101927851  .   -
chr1    235324564   235324565   NR_144491_RBM34         .   -
chr1    235097888   235291252   NR_002956_SNORA14B      .   -
chr1    235097869   235353431   NR_039908_MIR4753       .   -
chr1    235324564   235324565   NR_027762_RBM34         .   -
chr1    235324564   235324565   NM_001346738_RBM34      .   -
```

and gives me output as follows:

```
chr1:242627058-242627262,  242627060
```

where the `-` separated coordinates are from `file1` and the comma separated from second column of `file2`.

I have already tried using `awk` and while loop but for some reason I couldn't do it.

```
while read a b c; do col2=$b; col3=$3; tail -n +1 path/to/file2 | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{if($2>=$col2 && $2<=$col3) {print $a,$col2,$col3,$2}; break; else continue}' > rohit_TSS.txt; done < file1
```

Comment: Do you _only_ have data on chromosome 1 (`chr1`), or are there other chromosomes in the files (other values in the first column)? What are the actual _size_ of these files (data files used in bioinformatics can be quite big)?

Comment: There are other chromosome too. The file sizes are not greater than 5 MBs

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do this in 2 steps.

Throw everything into a helper file and sort.

```
awk 'FNR>1{print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' file1 file2 | sort -k1 >> file3
```

Then just run through them with `awk` in a single pass.

```
awk '{if (NF == 3) {chr=$1; lo=$2; hi=$3} else { if ($1==chr && $2>=lo && $2<=hi) print $1":"lo"-"hi", "$2}}' file3
```

A walk through the `awk`...... You know which lines in `file3` came from `file1` because they only have 3 fields, `file2` has more so....

```
if (NF == 3) {chr=$1; lo=$2; hi=$3}
```

is a test that is true when you are on a line (in `file3`) that came from `file1`. Every time you find a line from `file1` then you want to get the `lo` and `hi` values as well as the current chromosome

```
else
```

Otherwise we are on a line from `file2` so just.....

```
 if ($1==chr && $2>=lo && $2<=hi) print $1":"lo"-"hi", "$2}
```

And if we are in the same chromosome and the value of interest `$2` is between the `lo` and `hi` limits we remember from before then we print in your format.

Output was

```
chr1:235097868-235098170, 235097869
chr1:235097868-235098170, 235097888
```

**note**

In fact  you can forget the first `awk` and just

```
cat file1 file2 | sort > file3
```

And since it sorts on the entire line it should be `chr` agnostic.

Comment: hi @bu5hman. Can you help me understand what will ```(NF == 3) {chr=$1; lo=$2; hi=$3} ``` do? Because when I print it, it gives me awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="file3" FNR=1 NR=1. The command used was awk '{if (NF == 3) {chr=$1; lo=$2; hi=$3} print $chr, $lo, $hi}' file3 > filex

Comment: @RohitSatyam I don't think that the code that you quote appears at all in the answer.

Comment: The code you quote ` awk '{if (NF == 3) {chr=$1; lo=$2; hi=$3} print $chr, $lo, $hi}' file3` runs fine on my machine. Have included a bit of an explanation above, Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
for C in `cat file2 |awk -F" " '{ print $2 }' ` ; do 
   echo "Checking $C .." ;
   cat file1 | awk -v var=$C -F" " '{ if ( var  >=$2 && var <=$3 ) print $1":"$2"-"$3", "var  ;  }'; 
done
```

Later u can remove echo "Checking $C .." ;

```
Checking 234765055 ..
Checking 234782033 ..
Checking 234859787 ..
Checking 234895802 ..
Checking 235099745 ..
Checking 235324564 ..
Checking 235097888 ..
chr1:235097868-235098170, 235097888
Checking 235097869 ..
chr1:235097868-235098170, 235097869
Checking 235324564 ..
Checking 235324564 ..
```

Comment: Note that this will hurt if `file2` is several gigabytes big. You are also reading the entirety of `file1` _for each line_ in `file2`. This is very very slow.  Depending on the sizes of the files (which we know nothing about), you may want to read some of the data into an array in `awk` and then read the other file in the same `awk` program, or you may have to resort to reading lines from each file in an alternating fashion if both are very big (this would require that both files are sorted).

Comment: There's also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/133219 issues plus redundantly setting FS to its default value and putting a condition inside the action part of the awk script instead of in the condition part and other issues.